# max Qstring length allowed in Label - BB10 native apps

Tags: c++, qt, label, blackberry-10, maxlength

thanks for your attention and any suggestion/help you can provide:

Here we go :)

I have following layout in QML:

```
Page {
    ScrollView {
        scrollViewProperties {
            scrollMode: ScrollMode.Vertical
        }
        Container {
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            Label {
                id: label1
                objectName: qsTr("label1")
                textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                multiline: true
                textStyle.textAlign: TextAlign.Center
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my c++ code I'm setting a huge UTF-8 QString to this label:

```
/*
 * getData() - a helper function to take care of pulling everything from 
 * db and then packing it all and returning to caller
 */ 
QString text = getData();                                                        
label1->setText(text);
```

In most cases everything works fine. But in some cases when text.length() passes a certain limit, something trims out the end part of the string.

From debugging I can see the text.length in one of those cases is ~55000.
Also I verified that Label was able to **show text upto 3000 characters**.
Also I can say this without any doubt that this has nothing to do with ScrollView or Container.

No Label, ScrollView or Container documentation defines any kind of limit other than somewhere it says that **it can be device dependent**.

I also tried using a TextArea but without much help, it went upto ~4000 characters.

So, finally, ***is there a known char limit for Label or TextArea***, or if it's a device dependent thing then how can I overcome this issue? Please help.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, for now I'm using WebView and this is enabling me to show large strings without any unwanted hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I got a limit of 35716 with this code:

```
           Label {
                    onCreationCompleted: {
                        var texte = "0 ";
                        var count = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < 12000; i ++) {
                            count += count.toString().length + 1;
                            texte = texte + " " + count;
                        }
                        text = texte;
                    }
                    multiline: true
                    text: ""
                }
```

We should add this in a ticket into the BlackBerry bugTracker : https://www.blackberry.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Sorry, now it is in english

Comment: Anyway, you can cut your string at the nearest space every 10000 characters (for instance) and dynamically add a Label with this text

Comment: I guess it is a INT_MAX for 16 bit signed int (32768) with errors

Comment: I thought of the same thing, but as I have some tap listeners on the label it will become nearly impossible to manage all events. Also the last time I tried it, I was not pleased by the end result for two reasons: 1) it truncates at an arbitrary position and not after a complete word or sentence (that would require more of string processing than what should be required). and 2) text output format doesn't look natural as sometimes last line of the preceding Label only holds [one] character.

Answer (score 0):

Know limit for `TextArea` widget could be found in the documentation ([TextArea maximum length](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__textarea.html#property-maximumlength)):

> The default maximumLength is INT_MAX, meaning there is no limit set.
>   Although there is no limit set, the actual limit is a large finite
>   value and is device dependent.

Although, there's no such property for specifically `Label` widget I guess it has the same value as all of the classes inherited from [`AbstractTextControl`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__abstracttextcontrol.html) use [`QString`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qstring.html) for holding text to be displayed and the type used for returning the [length of `QString` is `int`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qstring.html#length)

Comment: setMaximumLength (intmaximumLength);
has no effect and I'm already using QString for the text.

Do you know how I can print the value for 'device dependent'.
My guess is that app fetches complete text from sqlite (as I'm printing it in logs after sqlite processing) but while rendering it on device screen it goes out of memory or something and thus truncates text at that point.

Comment: "device dependent" thing means that you'd get different `INT_MAX` values on different platforms since that definition depends on a particular target system and defined in `/BBNDK_ROOT/VERSION/qnx6/usr/include/limits.h` So to get this value you just need to print it out. I'd suggest you may ignore this point as all BB devices are using the same platform. If you using `slog2info` for getting the logs I did notice (http://goo.gl/SdOp9m7) that it truncates the text on output. Isn't it your case by any chance?

Comment: yes it does. But here is how I'm assuring that I have complete text before showing it in the Label:

Comment: qDebug() << "getdata() end value: " << text << "\nlines array size: " << textarray.size() << "\ntext length: " << text.length();